# Thinkpad X220 will not boot Kernel 5.3.*

Tags: linux-mint, boot, thinkpad

My Thinkpad X220 runs Mint Linux 19.3 Tricia. it's not dual boot. When I tried to upgrade recently the new kernel was 5.3.0-42 but it won't boot that so currently using 5.0.0-32.
I get error messages USB not accepting address error -110. Eventually it just hangs or I get bored and power off! Same happens if I try a live Ubuntu USB stick. I've edited my GRUB menu so the working kernel is default but I'd like to use the latest. I don't even know how to retrieve the error logs from the failed boot. When I use dmesg I just get the stuff that is currently working. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I have done all updates on my X220 running kernel 5.3.0-53-generic with no problem.

Try adding `noapic` on the Linux line in the boot configuration.